# EAP 7 What is the default Quality-Of-Service of a JMS Bridge?

Tags: jboss, jms, bridge

The docu is just mentioning the three options:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/7.0/pdf/Configuring_Messaging/Red_Hat_JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform-7.0-Configuring_Messaging-en-US.pdf

But what is the default value? (I assume AT_MOST_ONCE but please confirm)
AT_MOST_ONCE
DUPLICATES_OK
ONCE_AND_ONLY_ONCE

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The default value is `AT_MOST_ONCE`. You can verify it using CLI command

> [standalone@localhost:9990 /]
>   /subsystem=messaging-activemq/jms-bridge=my-jms-bridge:read-attribute(name=quality-of-service,include-defaults=true,resolve-expressions=true)
>   {
>       "outcome" => "success",
>       "result" => "AT_MOST_ONCE" }